# URL ReWrite with Toro Script (Force trailing slash)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know this question is fairly over-asked!

But every situation is different… and I’m not very good at .htaccess modifications.

Currently I am using a PHP index routing script from [Toro](http://toroweb.org/). In which I have an .htaccess file that includes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1/ [L]
```

How can I force the URL to use a trailing slash? What is the best solution in getting this done so I don’t have duplicate content on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect to trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# your old rules, except don't need trailing slash in target
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```